# animating views b/w fragments or actionbar

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-animation

I have two fragments on an activity and I want to show a transition (linear animation) on a view from one fragment to another.

Note: I am talking about a view in a fragment moving/animation towards another fragment and not transitioning fragments itself.

One possible solution I was able to think of was to change my screen from using fragments to just plain fragment activity since I dont think there is a way to move a view object from one fragment to another? Technically speaking two fragments does not share views b/w them and so If I move anything to or fro b/w them, Ill be easily able to see the cut off part while moving views (when the view gets to the very end of the fragment to get towards another fragment). I might be wrong over here, but then again I couldn't find anything online to do such. It seems completely absurd to rewrite whole screen just to show acceleration/deceleration/linear animations.

Is there a way to do such animations? If this is not possible then is it possible to create such animation b/w a fragment and an action bar? How can I do it? Can anyone please provide me a link for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although transitions (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html) do not move the view from one fragment to another, they may actually still give you the effect you are looking for.

If you take a look at the video's in this blog post series you may find one that matches what you want (for example the video 3.2): http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html